# IPC reader-writer without starvation

Tags: c, ipc

I'm trying to implement a functional version of the classic reader-writer problem in IPC which doesn't cause starvation. [You can find the full article here](http://cit.fer.hr/index.php/CIT/article/view/1561/1265)

The code is working. What do you think, is it coherent with the paper? How could I implement it using `semop`?

Here's the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define TEST_ERROR    if (errno) {fprintf(stderr,           \
                      "%s:%d: PID=%5d: Error %d (%s)\n", \
                      __FILE__,         \
                      __LINE__,         \
                      getpid(),         \
                      errno,            \
                      strerror(errno));}

//third read-writer problem
int readers, writers;

int main()
{

    struct sembuf sops_mutex, sops_resource;
    int sem_mutex, sem_resource, shm_id, *list, i, j, status;
    pid_t child_pid;

    shm_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(list), 0666 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL); 
    TEST_ERROR;

    list = shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);
    TEST_ERROR; 

    sem_mutex = semget((key_t)getpid(), 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);
    TEST_ERROR;

    sem_resource = semget((key_t)getpid()+1, 1, 0600 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL); 
    TEST_ERROR;

    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               
    semctl(sem_resource, 0, SETVAL, 1);       //signal(mutex)               



    //i%2==0 reader else writer
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
        switch(fork()) {
            case 0:


            switch(i%2) {
                case 0://reader

                    while(semctl(sem_mutex, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)

                    if(writers > 0 || readers == 0) {
                        semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               
                        while(semctl(sem_resource, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)
                        while(semctl(sem_mutex, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)
                    }

                    readers++;
                    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               

                    for(j = 0; j<20; j++) { //reading
                        if(j%2!=0)
                            printf("%lld %d ", (long long)getpid(), list[j]);
                    }printf("\n");

                    while(semctl(sem_mutex, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)
                    readers--;
                    if(readers==0)
                        semctl(sem_resource, 0, SETVAL, 1);       //signal(resource)                
                    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               


                    break;

                default://writer

                    while(semctl(sem_mutex, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)
                    writers++;                                //writers <- +1
                    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               
                    while(semctl(sem_resource, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(resource)

                    list[i] = i; //writing

                    while(semctl(sem_mutex, 0, GETVAL) != 1); //wait(mutex)
                    writers--;                  
                    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, SETVAL, 1);          //signal(mutex)               
                    semctl(sem_resource, 0, SETVAL, 1);       //signal(resource)                

                    break;

            }

            shmdt(list);
            TEST_ERROR;         


            exit(0);
            break;

            default:
                break;

        }

    }

    while (shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) {
        TEST_ERROR;
    }

    while((child_pid = wait(&status)) != -1) {
        printf("PARENT: %lld, CHILD_TERMINATED: %d STATUS: %d \n", (long long)getpid(), child_pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));        
    }   

    semctl(sem_resource, 0, IPC_RMID);
    semctl(sem_mutex, 0, IPC_RMID); 

}
```

This is the wait-signal portion
[image: This is the wait-signal portion]

And this is the code of interest
[image: Code of interest]

Comment: @chux with testing you'll see that sometimes the readers can't read all the writings done, that's not an error i guess it's for scheduling reasons

Comment: BTW: `"%d"` is not necessarily the matching specifier for the return type of  `getpid()`.  Usual  fix is `printf("%lld", (long long) getpid());`